# Laravel with nginx Https showing not secure

Tags: nginx, https

I configured laravel 5.4 with nginx https. The pages are loading with https. I configured with ssl certificate and ssl key in nginx configuration file. But still its showing not secured.

**This is my nginx config file**
    server

```
{
         listen 80;
         #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
         listen 443 ssl;

         root /usr/share/nginx/html/project;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
           server_name project.dev;
          ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

          access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
          error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

          location / {
                # proxy_pass $uri:8181;
                #proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
          }

         location ~ \.php$ {
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                 #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
    }
```

**This is my .htaccess file**
    
       
           Options -MultiViews

```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Where did you get the certificate from? Is it valid and verified?

Comment: I just followed steps which is given in nginx configuration with https in www.digitalocean.com

Comment: What does ssllabs.com says? What does the console of your browser says?

Comment: I didn't follow ssllabs.com I didn't get any error in my console. My project also running fine with https. But it shows unsecure.